# Bash: Can Logging Influence Variable Scope?

Tags: bash, scope, io-redirection, tee, process-substitution

In my current project, I run a loop that during execution defines a variable that is required later on. 
Everything worked well until I wanted to add logging with tee, so that I 
later could inspect the log also in a file. 
As I wanted to log both, stdout and stderr, I applied `|&` (the shortcut of `2>&1 |`). 
But strangely, the variable's value gets lost then.

```
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
    # ... do something meaningful ...
    myVar=test1
done |& tee test1
echo "myVar=$myVar"
```

Output:

```
myVar=
```

Meanwhile I found a way, that works better: When I switch to a combination of *file redirection* and *process substitution*, the variable definition works.

```
for i in 1 2 3 ; do 
    # ... do something meaningful ...
    myVar=test2
done > >(tee test2    ) \
    2> >(tee test2 >&2)
echo "myVar=$myVar"
```

Output:

```
myVar=foo
```

But I want to understand, why :-)

1. Why does the value get lost in the first example?
2. Why doesn't it get lost in the second?

Can you tell?

Comment: Using pipe creates a subshell on either side of the pipe, when it ends both close losing the environment inside. It has nothing to do with tee, try it with any command. Second way only creates a subshell for `>()` so anything not in there is not lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As 123 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034040/bash-can-logging-influence-variable-scope#comment79030834_46034040) a pipe creates a sub shell (a new scope) and a sub shell has no access to the variables of the parent shell.

The following helper function shows the PID of the shell and the value of the variable `a`.

```
show_a () { echo $BASHPID: a=$a >&2; }
```

The following example creates no sub shell, because only redirection is used. Only one variable `a` is used.

```
$ a=1; show_a; { a=2; show_a; } > /dev/null ; show_a
31072: a=1
31072: a=2
31072: a=2
```

But this example creates a sub shell, because of the pipe. And each process has its own variable `a`.

```
$ a=1; show_a; { a=2; show_a; } | tee ; show_a
31072: a=1
6375: a=2
31072: a=1
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you both. Nice trick to print $BASHPID during execution.